# Term to describe someone's lack of interest in festive activities

Tags: single-word-requests

I am someone who doesn't care if someone doesn't buy me a present on my birthday. I don't care if my girlfriend proposes that we not do anything on Valentine's Day and maybe go out another time. It doesn't have to be February 14th that we celebrate it, or even the month of February, I don't really care. I don't need to have a Christmas tree to celebrate Christmas.

I'm also not very materialistic. I don't want anything for Christmas, and I perceive almost everything people buy me as useless.

Just to make things clear, I am not anti-holiday. I am basically the opposite of the girl who cries because her boyfriend gave her just chocolate on Valentine's Day but didn't offer to go out somewhere to celebrate.

Is there a word that describes my attitude and personality?

Comment: Indifferent, easy going, unattached …

Comment: Do you attend mass on these religious festivities? IMO if we know the answer to this, then finding that term will be easier

Comment: ***Non-materialist*** and ***non-traditionalist*** seem to cover some of the aspects of what you're talking about.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I am atheist. It has nothing to do with beliefs. It is simply that I do not care about these things. It's not that I am forcing myself to be against it

Comment: Dispassionate, or detached?

Comment: You'd be "non-materialistic" if you didn't want a gift but wanted to spend Valentine's Day/Christmas/other occasions with loved ones. If you've genuinely no interest in spending them with loved ones or marking them at all, I don't think there's a word for that. Unless it fits in with a wider worldview/character (nihilist, non-conformist, Jehovah's Witness, antisocial, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are ***ascetic***?

> **Ascetic**: a person who leads an austerely simple life, especially one who abstains from the normal pleasures of life or denies himself or herself material satisfaction - [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ascetic)
>
> **Ascetic**: One who is extremely rigorous in the practice of self-denial, whether by seclusion or by abstinence from creature comforts. - [OED.com](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11367)

Answer (score 0):

Nonchalant (adjective) : She smiled down at her and tried to correct posture and look very cool and nonchalant at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**Wet blanket**. This often used more in the sense of active disproval than mere ambivalence. But it works fine when you are expected to make an effort which exceeds your personal enthusiasm. Valentines Day certainly qualifies. Apparently, it comes from throwing a wet blanket on a fire.

> noun INFORMAL
>
> a person who spoils other people's fun by failing to join in with or
>   by disapproving of their activities.

"Wet blanket."  google Dictionary, 6 Dec. 2018.

> : one that quenches or dampens enthusiasm or pleasure

"Wet Blanket." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 6 Dec. 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Your attitude toward the holiday season could be described as

From Merriam-Webster:

> [apathetic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathetic) *adjective* ap·​a·​thet·​ic | \ˌa-pə-ˈthe-tik  \
>
> 1 : having or showing little or no feeling or emotion : SPIRITLESS
>
> 2 : having little or no interest or concern : INDIFFERENT

Within this definition, I think indifferent would be more accurate

OR

You may simply live a stoic lifestyle, shown in your attitude toward the holidays.

> [Stoic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stoical) *adjective* (ˈstoʊɪkəl  ; stōˈikəl)
>
> 1. showing austere indifference to joy, grief, pleasure, or pain; calm and unflinching under suffering, bad fortune, etc.

For context - an [Bonus Article](https://www.newsweek.com/stoicism-could-be-key-happiness-1145903) by Newsweek on a 'stoic' lifestyle and why it can be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your description makes me think of someone who is

> **otherworldly**
>
> more closely connected to spiritual things than to the ordinary things of life

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherworldly)

Comment: It's not clear to me that the OP is at all concerned with spiritual things.